# android get Image from URL and save in SQLite database and after setting it to Bitmap

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap, android-sqlite, android-file

I have the code for downloading image from URL to SDCard, but my device can set up the image ONLY from bitmap. 
The question is how I can consume image from URL directly into SQLite Database and then retreive it as the bitmap?

Thanks for any help

```
public void getNewLogoFromURL(String logo) throws IOException {
        new GetLogo().execute(logo);
    }

    class GetLogoForReceipt extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                downloadFile(params[0]);
            } catch ( IOException e ) {

            }
            return null;
        }
    }

     public void downloadFile(String url) throws IOException {
            DataOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                File dest_file = new File("/sdcard/Pictures/applicationLogo.png");
                URL u = new URL(url);
                URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
                int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
                DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());
                byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
                stream.readFully(buffer);
                stream.close();
                 fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest_file));
                fos.write(buffer);
                fos.flush();
            } finally {
                fos.close();
            }
        }

//Device image settingUp code

    String[] fileList = { "applicationLogo.png" };
        Bitmap[] bitmap = new Bitmap[fileList.length];

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/Pictures/applicationLogo.png", options);

        for ( int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++ ) {
            bitmap[i] = bitmap2;
        }
        int ret;
        printer = new LinePrinter();
        ret = printer.open(device);
        ret = printer.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 2):

Storing bitmaps/images in sqlite database is a bad idea. Download the image to the sd card and save the location in the data base and retrieve the image from sd card when you required.
The below code shows getting bitmap from sdcard.

```
public Bitmap createBitMap(String path){
File file = new File(path);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
return bitmap;
```

}

Comment: Many thanks for answer. Actually the idea is not to leave access to my application's files in sdcard, because my application has to use them, but if somebody would delete them.... that's why I want to put them inside DB and then retreive them when I need them.